# How to distinguish QLowEnergyDescriptor's from each other?

Tags: c++, qt, bluetooth-lowenergy, qt5

QLowEnergyService emits the signal of

```
descriptorWritten(const QLowEnergyDescriptor &descriptor, const QByteArray &newValue)
```

In my device its custom service has over 10 characteristics and 10 QBluetoothUuid::ClientCharacteristicConfiguration descriptors.

When descriptors cоme alone they are all look the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the way.

Each characteristic or descriptor has an unique handle number in a GATT table. And both QLowEnergyCharacteristic and QLowEnergyDescriptor class has the handle() method. Each primary service of the device owns a certain range of handles. So if I know this structure of GATT I can dispatch response message of descriptorWritten() to the right method with it's parent service and/or characteristic.

To obtain the GATT table in Linux I used 2 tools hcitool and gatttool.

```
$ sudo hcitool lescan
LE Scan ...
CA:A7:24:3E:00:5E (unknown)
CA:A7:24:3E:00:5E MI Band 2

$ sudo gatttool -b CA:A7:24:3E:00:5E -I -t random
[CA:A7:24:3E:00:5E][LE]> connect
Attempting to connect to CA:A7:24:3E:00:5E
Connection successful
[CA:A7:24:3E:00:5E][LE]> primary
attr handle: 0x0001, end grp handle: 0x0007 uuid: 00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
attr handle: 0x0008, end grp handle: 0x000b uuid: 00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
attr handle: 0x000c, end grp handle: 0x0016 uuid: 0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
attr handle: 0x0017, end grp handle: 0x001c uuid: 00001530-0000-3512-2118-0009af100700
attr handle: 0x001d, end grp handle: 0x0023 uuid: 00001811-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
attr handle: 0x0024, end grp handle: 0x0026 uuid: 00001802-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
attr handle: 0x0027, end grp handle: 0x002c uuid: 0000180d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
attr handle: 0x002d, end grp handle: 0x0051 uuid: 0000fee0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
attr handle: 0x0052, end grp handle: 0x0066 uuid: 0000fee1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CA:A7:24:3E:00:5E][LE]> char-desc
handle: 0x0001, uuid: 00002800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0002, uuid: 00002803-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0003, uuid: 00002a00-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0004, uuid: 00002803-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0005, uuid: 00002a01-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0006, uuid: 00002803-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0007, uuid: 00002a04-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0008, uuid: 00002800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0009, uuid: 00002803-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x000a, uuid: 00002a05-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x000b, uuid: 00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x000c, uuid: 00002800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x000d, uuid: 00002803-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x000e, uuid: 00002a25-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x000f, uuid: 00002803-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0010, uuid: 00002a27-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0011, uuid: 00002803-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0012, uuid: 00002a28-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0013, uuid: 00002803-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0014, uuid: 00002a23-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0015, uuid: 00002803-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0016, uuid: 00002a50-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0017, uuid: 00002800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0018, uuid: 00002803-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0019, uuid: 00001531-0000-3512-2118-0009af100700
handle: 0x001a, uuid: 00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x001b, uuid: 00002803-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x001c, uuid: 00001532-0000-3512-2118-0009af100700
handle: 0x001d, uuid: 00002800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x001e, uuid: 00002803-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x001f, uuid: 00002a46-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0020, uuid: 00002901-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0021, uuid: 00002803-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0022, uuid: 00002a44-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0023, uuid: 00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0024, uuid: 00002800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0025, uuid: 00002803-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0026, uuid: 00002a06-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0027, uuid: 00002800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0028, uuid: 00002803-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0029, uuid: 00002a37-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x002a, uuid: 00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x002b, uuid: 00002803-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x002c, uuid: 00002a39-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x002d, uuid: 00002800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x002e, uuid: 00002803-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x002f, uuid: 00002a2b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0030, uuid: 00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0031, uuid: 00002803-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0032, uuid: 00000020-0000-3512-2118-0009af100700
handle: 0x0033, uuid: 00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0034, uuid: 00002803-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0035, uuid: 00000001-0000-3512-2118-0009af100700
handle: 0x0036, uuid: 00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0037, uuid: 00002803-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0038, uuid: 00000002-0000-3512-2118-0009af100700
handle: 0x0039, uuid: 00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x003a, uuid: 00002803-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x003b, uuid: 00000003-0000-3512-2118-0009af100700
handle: 0x003c, uuid: 00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x003d, uuid: 00002803-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x003e, uuid: 00002a04-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x003f, uuid: 00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0040, uuid: 00002803-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0041, uuid: 00000004-0000-3512-2118-0009af100700
handle: 0x0042, uuid: 00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0043, uuid: 00002803-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0044, uuid: 00000005-0000-3512-2118-0009af100700
handle: 0x0045, uuid: 00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0046, uuid: 00002803-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0047, uuid: 00000006-0000-3512-2118-0009af100700
handle: 0x0048, uuid: 00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0049, uuid: 00002803-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x004a, uuid: 00000007-0000-3512-2118-0009af100700
handle: 0x004b, uuid: 00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x004c, uuid: 00002803-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x004d, uuid: 00000008-0000-3512-2118-0009af100700
handle: 0x004e, uuid: 00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x004f, uuid: 00002803-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0050, uuid: 00000010-0000-3512-2118-0009af100700
handle: 0x0051, uuid: 00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0052, uuid: 00002800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0053, uuid: 00002803-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0054, uuid: 00000009-0000-3512-2118-0009af100700
handle: 0x0055, uuid: 00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0056, uuid: 00002803-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0057, uuid: 0000fedd-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0058, uuid: 00002803-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0059, uuid: 0000fede-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x005a, uuid: 00002803-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x005b, uuid: 0000fedf-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x005c, uuid: 00002803-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x005d, uuid: 0000fed0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x005e, uuid: 00002803-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x005f, uuid: 0000fed1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0060, uuid: 00002803-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0061, uuid: 0000fed2-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0062, uuid: 00002803-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0063, uuid: 0000fed3-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0064, uuid: 00002803-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0065, uuid: 0000fec1-0000-3512-2118-0009af100700
handle: 0x0066, uuid: 00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CA:A7:24:3E:00:5E][LE]>
```

As you can see there are 18 different handles with the same UUID **00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb** of CCC descriptors.

Answer (score 0):

The slot function signature contains `const QLowEnergyDescriptor &ccd`, you can call it's uuid() function to compare the uuids with a list of your uuids.

Comment: It will be 10 descriptors with the same UUID QBluetoothUuid::ClientCharacteristicConfiguration = 0x2902.

Comment: Indeed. But any CC can (iirc also must) contain one CCCD with UUID 0x2902. What I suggested was that you can infer which CCCD you have by looking at it's parent UUID, since all descriptors are arranged in a hierarchy. So any descriptor with UUID 0x2902 must have a parent (with a unique UUID). The trick - when using Qt - is to have individual Slots for each BLE-Service of your device. This way, when you receive a 'descriptor-written'-signal, you know from which service the event originated, as each service has it's own slot.